# integrate wordpress with laravel, but on separate server

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx

I Have a wordpress blog in a subdomain of my website like this
`blog.domain.com`
and is on a separate server.

but now I want to use it as a route of my domain like this
`domain.com/blog`

how can I do that and keep it on the separate server ?

can I do this using laravel ?

my webserver is nginx.

Comment: what you are thinking is different server, called by your route, a different server will have its own IP address, atmost you can do is redirect to that server when user comes to `domain.com/blog`

Comment: yes it's possible to redirect, but I want to it's address be like ```domain.com/blog/post/1``` without redirect to a different address, is it possible ?